# What is performance of label correcting algorithm?

Tags: performance, algorithm, label

I have tried to find answer in Google but without any result. I guess, it should be like performance of **Dijkstra algorithm - O(E*logV)** - since this both algorithms are really similar to each other. Am I right?

Comment: That's not what wikipedia says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is `O(V * E)`. A proof is in this [article](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-082j-network-optimization-fall-2010/lecture-notes/MIT15_082JF10_lec07.pdf).

Comment: Yay, thank you very much, you saved a lot of my time.